# Laravel unexpected redirects ( 302 )

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have started a new Laravel 5.2 project, using `laravel new MyApp`, and added authentication via `php artisan make:auth`. This is intended to be a members only website, where the first user is seeded, and creates the rest (no manual user creation/password reset/etc).

These are the routes I have currently defined:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  // Authentication Routes...
  Route::get( 'user/login',  ['as' => 'user.login',     'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm']);
  Route::post('user/login',  ['as' => 'user.doLogin',   'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login'        ]);

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    // Authenticated user routes
    Route::get( '/', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=> 'HomeController@index']);
    Route::get( 'user/{uid?}', ['as' => 'user.profile',   'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@profile' ]);
    Route::get( 'user/logout', ['as' => 'user.logout',    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@logout'  ]);
    Route::get( '/user/add',   ['as' => 'user.add',       'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showAddUser']);

    [...]
  });
});
```

I can login just fine, however I'm experiencing some very "funky" behavior - when I try to logout ( via the built-in `logout` method that was created via artisan ), the page does a 302 redirect to home, and I am still logged in.

What's more, while almost all pages (not listed here) work as expected, user.add also produces a 302 to the home page.

Do note the homepage is declared to the AuthController as `$redirectTo`, if that makes any difference

I found out about the redirects via the debugbar.  Any idea on what to look for ?

Comment: For those who have upgraded Laravel recently, check the syntax of your middleware in your controllers. It likely needs to be updated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After several hours of hair pulling, I have found my answer -- and it's silly.

The problem is that the route `user.profile` has a path `user/{uid?}` and it matches both `user/logout` and `user/add` as paths.

It being before the others, and not having a regex or similar, it handled the route.

I still don't know why a 302 was generated for *that* page, but found that moving it out of the `AuthController` and into the `UserController` (where it should be from the start) fixed the behavior.

Thus, my (amended and working) routes now look like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  // Authentication Routes...
  Route::get( 'user/login',  ['as' => 'user.login',     'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm']);
  Route::post('user/login',  ['as' => 'user.doLogin',   'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login'        ]);

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    // Authenticated user routes
    Route::get( '/',     ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=> 'HomeController@index']);
    Route::get( '/home', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=> 'HomeController@home']);
    Route::get( 'user/logout', ['as' => 'user.logout',    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@logout'  ]);

    // *** Added /profile/ here to prevent matching with other routes ****
    Route::get( 'user/profile/{uid?}', ['as' => 'user.profile',   'uses' => 'UserController@profile' ]);
    Route::get( '/user/add',           ['as' => 'user.add',       'uses' => 'UserController@showAddUser']);

    [...]
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 I've been tearing my hair out all afternoon with a similar problem. I never thought to look in which order the routes were in.

Answer (score 28):

I got the same issue and i solved it by adding the header with accept:'application/json'. And I think I checked the source code before which indicates that if you don't add this, it might redirect when you are using the auth middleware. But I am not sure if it is the case and I cannot recall where i found this.

Comment: I can confirm this solved the problem for me. The request was invalid (`$this->validate($request...)` was returning the redirect), but Laravel didn't detected that the request was made from Ajax so instead of returning a JSON object, it tried to redirect. I'm using Laravel 5.3.

Comment: I can confirm the same thing, suddenly I was getting this behaviour out of no-where, except the `Accept` header was missing telling it to accept `application/json` instead of `*/*`.

Comment: Was having the same issue in Laravel, spent hours pulling my hair out testing the API in insomnia and not understanding what was going on

Answer (score 20):

I encountered an issue with 302 Redirects when posting ajax requests. The solution in this case was to remember to include the CSRF token.

See the Laravel 5.4 documents here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Comment: I also had this problem during an ajax requests where I am validating some datas. And the field to validate was not matching the field in the form.

Answer (score 13):

For me it was `guest` middleware!

This middleware redirects user to homepage if authenticated.
You don't have to use it for `Api` requests. So I removed it and the problem solved.

Comment: Genius! I would never have thought the guest check would be the cause of my issues.

Comment: This was the fix for me too! Many thanks mate

Comment: How did you remove them?

Answer (score 1):

May be default redirect page after logout is `home` and seems like you do not have `home` in your `web` route. Try the below code in your `AuthController.php`

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins; // after this line
$redirectAfterLogout = 'login' // add this line
```

This will redirect you to `login` page after logout. You can change it to any route if you wish. I used `login` as an example.

**OR**

You can change after logout route in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

```
public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : 'login');
    }
```

I changed the default route to `login`. If you don't have `$redirectAfterLogout` in your `AuthController.php` it will look here for redirect path. I don't suggest people to edit here, it's kind of hard coding.

Comment: `Route::get( '/', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=> 'HomeController@index']);` This is a `home` route, but you can't access it unless you're logged in. You are correct though, a `redirect` from `logout` should, by default, return to the `login` page.

Comment: as said above, `home` is the name of the route -- and what I see is that the request goes to `AuthController@logout` and gets redirected to `HomeController@index`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it turned out I had a route:redirect inside my ajax controller.
which doesn't make sense because obviously we have to return ajax but I was returning a route!

Answer (score 1):

I use a lot ajax (get & post) and with every response I update the token with `session()->regenerate()` on the server, then on the client side I update every token field with js.
But last week, I delete by mistake the one liner function to do that. So, suddenly the system starts to give a 302 response after the second call. It was so hard to find what was going on, because it works sometimes (firstime) and sometimes don't.
After I realize it was a token mismatch, I struggle a couple of days trying to find why, because the response don't point a token mismatch, just the 302 redirect.
Finally, I find the problem by dd() both tokens on the `tokensMatch()` function. I don't know why it won't trigger a TokenMismatch.

I hope this anecdote help you.

Answer (score 1):

If your website doesn't use HTTPS you have to define the following attribute in your .env

```
SESSION_SAME_SITE=Strict
```

Note: this precaution applied by some browsers to prevent exploit website's users

Answer (score 1):

As for me encountered 302 status during saving and what fixed that was inserting
Accept: application/json on ajax header, because i hava a script inside the php file.

```
               $.ajax({
                url:'{{route('fetchMunCit')}}' +'/'+id,
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                Accept: application/json
                    success:function(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced this issue in the login page which worked fine previously. So thought have a look at the directory permissions and it resulted the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 user user     4096 Jun 27  2019 storage
```

So storage directory has 755 permission which means only the owner has write access, Since that directory owned by "user" others like laravel can't write into it.

Changing the directory to 777 with this cmd resolved my issue:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R PROJECT_PATH/storage
```

**The right way,**

Since making that directory world-writable isn't the right way, make that directory owned by apache and set 775 to storage.. and it worked again.

```
sudo chown -R user:www-data PROJECT_PATH/storage
sudo chmod 775 -R PROJECT_PATH/storage
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was this in my controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was config/session.php

I changed some values there for production app like path, secure, same_site

But on local due to http://localhost, Secure session was failing to create any cookies.

That's why Authenticate middleware redirecting to login page with status 302

Answer (score 0):

I modified my login route by ***adding `AS` to it's parameter's array*** and it worked for me.

> **`Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'loginController@index']);`**

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is experiencing this.

My case was that the APP_URL value is different from the actual URL hence I was getting 302 error.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i managed to debug it with `dd()`-ing inside Exception folder handler.php.
I found that its always about CSRF_TOKEN MISMATCH
but every configuration was right

I then found out that http redirection (or request sending) to https or vice versa could mess up with csrf token validation, so I went to direct admin and forced ssl-redirection. and it solved my problem like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was making an **ajax call**. But what really caused the error was the **payload not passing my request validation rules**. I fixed data sent via ajax POST and 302 error has gone.