# Ajax Post Laravel got 302 Not Found

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to ask about Ajax at Laravel.

Here I make a profile update.

Previously using ajax all worked as they should. But for some reason I was required to use Ajax.

This is in my Controller file.

```php
/**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update()
    {
        $data = $this->request->all();
        // return $data;
        $validator = \Validator::make(
            $data,
            [
                'address' => 'required',
                'postal_code' => 'required|max:5',
                'country' => 'required',
                'province_id' => 'required|exists:indoregion_provinces,id',
                'city_id' => 'required|exists:indoregion_regencies,id',
            ],
            [
                'address.required' => 'Address is required',
                'postal_code.required' => 'Postal Code is required',
                'postal_code.max' => 'Max character is :max',
                'country.required' => 'Country is required',
                'province_id.required' => 'Province is required',
                'province_id.exists' => 'Province is not exists',
                'city_id.required' => 'City is required',
                'city_id.exists' => 'City is not exists',
            ]
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }

        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);

        $posted = [];

        foreach ($validator->getRules() as $key => $value) {
            $val = $this->request->{$key};

            if (is_null($val) || $val == '') {
                continue;
            }

            $posted[$key] = $val;
        }

        foreach ($posted as $key => $value) {
            $user{$key} = $value;
        }
        return redirect('/home')->with(
            'success',
            'Data profil berhasil disimpan.'
        );
    }
```

Then this is the route I made.

```php
Route::middleware(['auth', 'isActive', 'not-customer', 'phone-verified'])->group(function () {
    // KYC Partner
    Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index')->name('users.index');
    Route::post('users-update', 'UsersController@update')->name('users.update');
});
```

Finally Application of ajax on my blade.

```php
@extends('layouts.treasury')

@section('before_script')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/smart_wizard.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/smart_wizard_theme_dots.min.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap-validation.min.js') }}"></script>
    {{-- <script src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js')}}"></script> --}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .sw-btn-group {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .sw-btn-group-extra {
            display: none;
        }
        /* .error {
            color: red
        } */

        /* .select2 .select2-container .select2-container--default{
            width: 100% !important;
        } */

        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            .btn-group .btn {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
                theme: 'dots',
                transitionEffect: 'fade',
                transitionSpeed: '400',
                lang: { next: 'Next', previous: 'Prev'},
                toolbarSettings: {
                    toolbarButtonPosition: 'left',
                    showNextButton: true,
                    showPreviousButton: true,
                    toolbarExtraButtons: [
                        $('<button type="submit"></button>').text('Finish').addClass('btn btn--primary-2 text-white sw-btn-extra').on('click', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            var id_number = $("#id_number").val();
                            var id_card_scan = $("#id_card_scan").val();
                            var selfie_scan = $("#selfie_scan").val();
                            var address = $("#address").val();
                            var postal_code = $("#postal_code").val();
                            var country = $("#country").val();
                            var province_id = $("#province_id").val();
                            var city_id = $("#city_id").val();
                            var tax_id_number = $("#tax_id_number").val();
                            var taxpayer_number_scan = $("#taxpayer_number_scan").val();
                            var owner_name = $("#owner_name").val();
                            var account_number = $("#account_number").val();
                            var bank_id = $("#bank_id").val();
                            var branch = $("#branch").val();

                            $.ajax({

                                type:"POST",

                                url:"{{ route('users.update') }}",

                                data:{
                                    '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                                    "_method" : "POST",
                                    'id_number':id_number,
                                    'id_card_scan':id_card_scan,
                                    'selfie_scan':selfie_scan,
                                    'address':address,
                                    'postal_code':postal_code,
                                    'country':country,
                                    'province_id':province_id,
                                    'city_id':city_id,
                                    'tax_id_number':tax_id_number,
                                    'taxpayer_number_scan':taxpayer_number_scan,
                                    'owner_name':owner_name,
                                    'account_number':account_number,
                                    'bank_id':bank_id,
                                    'branch':branch
                                },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function () {
                                    console.log('success');
                                },
                                complete: function () {
                                    console.log('complete');
                                }

                            });

                        })
                    ]
                }
            })

            $('#myForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    selfie_scan: {
                        accept: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp",
                        filesize: 8388608
                    },
                    id_card_scan: {
                        accept: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp",
                        card_scan: 8388608
                    },
                    selfie_scan: {
                        accept: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp",
                        selfie_scan: 8388608
                    },
                    taxpayer_number_scan: {
                        accept: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp",
                        number_scan: 8388608
                    },
                    address: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    postal_code: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    country: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    province_id: {
                        required: true
                    },

                    city_id: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    id_number: {
                        digits: true,
                        maxlength: 16
                    },
                    tax_id_number: {
                        digits: true,
                        maxlength: 15
                    },
                    account_number: {
                        digits: true
                    }
                },
            });

            $('#smartwizard').on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {
                var elmForm = $("#form-step-" + stepNumber);
                if (stepDirection === 'forward' && elmForm) {
                    // elmForm.validator('validate');
                    // var elmErr = elmForm.children('.has-error');
                    // if (elmErr && elmErr.length > 0) {
                    //     return false;
                    // }
                    if ($('#myForm').valid()) {
                        return true
                    } else {
                        return false
                    }
                }
                return true;
            })
            $("#smartwizard").on("showStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {
                if($('button.sw-btn-next').hasClass('disabled')){
                    $('button.sw-btn-next').hide();
                    $('.sw-btn-group-extra').show(); // show the button extra only in the last page
                    $('.sw-btn-group-extra').css('width', '50%')
                    $('.sw-btn-extra').css('width', '100%')
                    $('.sw-btn-group').css('width', '48%')
                    $('button.sw-btn-prev').css('width', '100%');
                }else{
                    $('button.sw-btn-next').show();
                    $('.sw-btn-group').css('width', '100%')
                    $('.sw-btn-group-extra').hide();
                    $('button.sw-btn-prev').css('width', '50%');
                }

            });
        })
    </script>
@endsection

@section('content')
<section>
<div class="container">
    <form action="{{ route('users.update') }}" method="POST" id="myForm" role="form" data-toggle="validator" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div id="smartwizard">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#step-1">First<br /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#step-2">Second<br /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#step-3">Third<br /></a></li>
            </ul>

            <div>
                <div id="step-1" class="">
                    <div id="form-step-0" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">ID Card Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="id_number" id="id_number"
                                onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==16) return false;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">ID Card Picture (Maks. Ukuran 8MB)</label>
                            {{-- @if(!is_null(Auth::user()->photo))
                            <img alt="avatar"
                                    src="{{asset(Auth::user()->photo)}}"
                                    class="image--sm rounded"/>
                            @endif --}}
                            {{-- <input type="button" value="Pilih File" class="form-control" onclick="document.getElementById('id_card_scan').click()"> --}}
                            <input type="file" id="id_card_scan" name="id_card_scan" class="form-control" accept="image/*" capture="camera"  onchange="document.getElementById('filenameKTP').value=this.value">
                            <input type="text" id="filenameKTP" class="form-control" style="border: none;background-color: white" placeholder="tidak ada file" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="step-2" class="">
                    <div class="form-step-1" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
                            <textarea name="address" id="address" cols="30" rows="3" class="form-control">{{ !is_null(old('address')) ? old('address') : Auth::user()->address }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Postal Code</label>
                            <input type="number" value="{{ !is_null(old('postal_code')) ? old('postal_code') : Auth::user()->postal_code }}"
                            name="postal_code"
                            id="postal_code"
                            class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                            <select class="country form-control" name="country" id="country">
                                <option value="">== CHoose Country ==</option>
                                <option value="ID" selected>Indonesia</option>
                            </select>
                            <label id="country-error" class="error" for="country"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Province</label>
                            <select class="province form-control" name="province_id" id="province_id">
                                <option value="">== Choose Province ==</option>
                                @foreach (\App\Province::all() as $province)
                                    <option value="{{ $province->id }}" @if(Auth::user()->province_id == $province->id) selected @endif>{{ $province->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            <label id="province_id-error" class="error" for="province_id"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">City</label>
                            <select class="city form-control" name="city_id" id="city_id">
                                @if(!is_null(Auth::user()->city_id))
                                    <option value="{{ Auth::user()->city->id }}">{{ Auth::user()->city->name }}</option>
                                @else
                                    <option value="">== Choose City
                                        ==
                                    </option>
                                @endif
                            </select>
                            <label id="city_id-error" class="error" for="city_id"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="step-3" class="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Owner Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="owner_name" id="owner_name" class="form-control" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Account Number</label>
                        <input type="number" name="account_number" id="account_number"
                            onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==30) return false;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Bank Name</label>
                        <select class="bank" name="bank_id" id="bank_id">
                            <option value="">== Choose Bank ==</option>
                            @foreach(\App\Http\Controllers\BankAccountController::getListBank() as $bank)
                                <option value="{{ $bank->kliringrtgs_code }}">{{ $bank->bank_name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Branch (optional)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="branch" id="branch" value="{{ old('branch') }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</section>
@endsection
```

I hope that one of you will explain why this error arises and why it can be resolved.

Comment: do you include csrf_token read this before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020477/laravel-unexpected-redirects-302

Comment: Yes I have added it. `'_token': "{{csrf_token ()}}"`

Comment: You may have a route conflict. Can you please share the rest of your router file?

Comment: I have found the error. This is because I did not return the Ajax value itself. Like the status of the response if it works and fails. Can you give an example of returning a value to ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't uunderstand what you want correctly but i propose that:

```
$.ajax({

    type:"POST",

    url:"{{ route('users.update') }}",

    data:{
        '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        "_method" : "POST",
        'id_number':id_number,
        'id_card_scan':id_card_scan,
        'selfie_scan':selfie_scan,
        'address':address,
        'postal_code':postal_code,
        'country':country,
        'province_id':province_id,
        'city_id':city_id,
        'tax_id_number':tax_id_number,
        'taxpayer_number_scan':taxpayer_number_scan,
        'owner_name':owner_name,
        'account_number':account_number,
        'bank_id':bank_id,
        'branch':branch
       },
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (resp) {
           console.log('success');
           header = resp.getAllResponseHeaders()
           //and use informations in header or call resp to access response body

        },

   });
```

Comment: actually my mistake lies in the return value in the controller that I made. But you have corrected some of the ajax code that I made. Thank you very much for your help :)