# Laravel jquery ajax post controller always redirect (302)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a case where i'm calling ajax post to a controller and save data. I have tried in my development server it is working fine, but when i deploy to production, it is always redirecting

this is my js file

```js
function ajaxPost(Url,FormData){
 $.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
     'Accept':'application/json'
   }
 })
 return $.ajax({
   url : Url,
   type : "POST",
   data : FormData,
   dataType : "json",
 });
}

var FormData = {
  uuid : localStorage.getItem('uuid'),
  q_id : $select.data('question-id'),
  a_id : $(this).data('answer')
};
localStorage.setItem($select.data('question-id'), $(this).data('answer'));
ajaxPost('ajax/save', FormData).done(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    location.reload();
    $select.removeClass('question__slide-in question__slide-in-reverse').addClass('question__slide-out');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $select.attr('hidden', 'hidden');
    },450);
  }, 300);
});
```

this is the HomeController

```php
    public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->toArray();
        if(is_array($data['a_id'])){
            foreach($data['a_id'] as $value){
                $data = new UserAnswer();
                $data->user_id = $request->uuid;
                $data->question_id = $request->q_id;
                $data->answer_id = $value;
                if($request->has('custom'))
                    $data->custom_value = $request->custom;
                $data->save();
            }
        }else{
            $data = new UserAnswer();
            $data->user_id = $request->uuid;
            $data->question_id = $request->q_id;
            $data->answer_id = $request->a_id;
            if($request->has('custom'))
                $data->custom_value = $request->custom;
            $data->save();
        }

        return response()->json();
    }
```

web routes

```php
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::post('ajax/save', 'HomeController@save');
```

it is working in my dev as we can see in the image below. return 200 and the response header is application/json

development
[image]
but in the production (which im using AWS apache/2) getting 302 and response header is text/html

production
[image]
Appreciate all answer. Hopes it will solve my problem

Thank You

Comment: Is there a `Location` header in the response? If so, where is it sending you?

Comment: Also, should `$request->uuid` be `$request->id`? You aren't sending an `uuid` property

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020477/laravel-unexpected-redirects-302

Comment: hi @Phil thank you for your response
actually i'm sending uuid from the js also added the ajaxPost execution (code edited) . I already try to comment the **location.reload()** but still no luck

Comment: about location header response is  /public which the server always redirect to /public/

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're saying. Please just include the `Location` header in your screenshots.

Comment: It turns out that this case is a server issue where it cannot process post requests and after configuration the program runs smoothly. thank you for taking the time to help me @Phil

Comment: You should write up your own answer below. It might help somebody else in future