# Why Laravel `middleware('auth:sanctum')` causes 302 issues?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to get some data from a Laravel API endpoint but I'm getting some very unusual redirect issues and disallowed methods.  I will start by showing my javascript code first, then laravel code second.

First, I ran the following javascript code from the developer console of various websites with various top level domains to ensure I can authenticate without any CORS issues:

```
fetch("https://api.example.com/login",{
  method:"post",
  headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"email":"test@test.com","password":"test","remember_me":true})
})
.then(r=>r.json())
.then(r=>console.log(r));

// I get a perfect response like this:

{ data: { message: "Yay! Success!", token: "86|S5isCezrsYb1aToAsI3xZb9Ot9Tu7WU8XeOK1q8C" } }
```

I then take the token and do another get request from my developer console to the `/auth/user` end point to get my account details like this

```
fetch("https://api.example.com/auth/user",{
  method:"get",
  header:{
    Authorization:"Bearer 86|S5isCezrsYb1aToAsI3xZb9Ot9Tu7WU8XeOK1q8C",
    Accept: "application/json"
  },
})
.then(r=>r.json())
.then(r=>console.log(r));
```

But something completely weird happens.  The `https://api.example.com/auth/user` gives my developer console a `302` response.  Then my developer console automatically (without any intervention from me) makes a `GET` request to `https://api.example.com/login`.  The `https://api.example.com/login` then gives a `405` response with this message:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file /var/www/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117

#0 /var/www/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php(103): Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(Array, 'GET')
#1 /var/www/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php(40): Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#2 /var/www/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(162): 
...etc...
```

This is my Laravel code:

```
~/routes/api.php

Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Api\UserController@login']); //->middleware(['throttle:6,1']);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/auth/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


~/app/Http/Controller/Api/UserController.php

public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'message' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        ]);
        exit;
    } else if (!$user->active) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'message' => ['Your account approval is pending.'],
        ]);
        exit;
    }
    return response()->json([
        'data' => [
            "message" => __("Yay! Success!"),
            "token" => $user->createToken('authentication-token')->plainTextToken,
        ],
    ]);
}
```

So my question is, why can't the `/auth/user` endpoint return information about the user I'm logged in with?

---

EDIT

I tried `php artisan route:clear` which had no effect.

I tried changing the route from `/auth/user` to `authuser` in both the `route/api.php` and my `fetch()` call, and suddenly I have a CORS error.   Is the `auth/` path a reserved word of some kind?

Oh...i guess this `config/cors.php` also matters:

```
    'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'auth/user',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
    ],
```

---

UPDATE

I created a few more routes like this:

```
~/routes/api.php
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('blah1', Api\Blah1::class)->only(['index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy']);
    Route::resource('blah2', Api\Blah1::class)->only(['index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy']);
    // .. etc...
    Route::get('/auth/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});

~/config/cors.php

    'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'auth/user',
        'blah*',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
    ],
```

I noticed that POSTMAN has ZERO problems getting information from `auth/user` and `blah1, blah2, etc...`

However, it is just the browser that will always give a 302 and cause a redirect when pinging `auth/user, blah1, blah2, etc...`.  FireFox shows me these responses:

[image]

If I remove the `middleware('auth:sanctum')`, then I no longer get the 405 and 302 issue. However, `$request->user()` becomes null without the `middleware('auth:sanctum')`.  I need a way to get the user information from `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Comment: try to php artisan route:clear. Or maybe you have conflicted route - try to change uri.

Comment: Unless you have custom CORS settings in your app, CORS shouldn't be a problem. Check (and maybe provide) the response headers here? `/auth/user` shouldn't be reserved in any way - the default Laravel path for this endpoint is `/user` (with the `api` prefixed) - I'm assuming you have removed the default `api` prefix from your routes as you are able to hit `https://api.example.com/login`? I would try testing the API token outside of a browser environment (i.e. something like Postman) so you can interrogate the response properly and bypass CORS issues.

Comment: Maksim, @AlexT thanks! I think I'm getting really close based on your suggestions.  I posted results of POSTMAN and FireFox header response.  Any other ideas?

Comment: may this has something to do with the CSRF token described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020477/laravel-unexpected-redirects-302

Comment: Hah, 302 is redirect. Add header Accept: application/json to postman.

Comment: actually...i really think it is the CSRF token issue.  I'l confirm later.  But when i maek the same browser client side call through the "nuxtjs auth", i don't have the auth issue.  I think i saw nuxtjs auth use axios to pass along the csrf token...will confirm later.  But i'm pretty sure that's the problem

Comment: You should also set a custom header "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest". Laravel's using this to determine xhr requests and give either a json or html response. Thats why this header is set as default for axios in bootstrap.js.

Comment: @Maksim's comment provided solution for me in postman.