# How to debug unwanted 302 redirect from Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, http, axios

I'm trying to get data from a database through this ajax request:

```
axios.get('/about-info')
```

**`web.php`**:

```
Route::get('/about-info', [CMSController::class, 'aboutInfo']);
```

**`CMSController.php`**:

```
public function aboutInfo()
{
    $data = DB::table('about_info')->first('order by id desc');
    return $data;
}
```

but instead I am getting the whole `welcome.blade.php` content. It looks like the `url` in `web.php` is not called and instead a redirect happens. The dev tools network tab shows a `302` redirect.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020477/laravel-unexpected-redirects-302) seems to have insight on this issue. I've been trying to implement answer 3 (adding `accept: 'application/json` to the `config/headers` object of the request) but the object already has that entry:

```
config:
    headers:
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
```

[This guide](https://warlord0blog.wordpress.com/2018/11/20/laravel-routing-returns-302-redirect/) is talking about `auth middleware` being the possible cause of this problem but I'm not using `middleware` (at least none I am aware of). Any idea how to get to the root of this?

Comment: Query should be like `DB::table('about_info')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()` to follow eloquent conventions, and your response: `return response()->json(['data' => $data]);`, make sure you have `use DB;` at the top of your Controller, etc. I don't think you're getting an error (would be a 500, not 302), and it _shouldn't_ be using any authentication middleware by default. If you manually navigate to `http://localhost:8000/about-info` (or whatever the URL is for your app), what do you see?

Comment: @TimLewis I made sure those things are in place and edited the `return` statement but nothing changed. I don't get an error, like I wrote in my post the `dev tools network` tab shows a `302 redirect`. When I navigate to `http://localhost:8000/about-info` I am getting a response with `welcome.blade.php` (index page) as `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the route to your api routes file? All routes in the web namespace receive session state, CSFR, and possibly more that could be getting in the way (i.e. "new session, go to the welcome screen!").

This would change your URL path to:

```
axios.get('/api/about-info')
```

Comment: Adding `api` to the url does not bring any change. Anything else I could try?

Comment: I don't think I was completely clear in my answer. Move the route definition for this operation out of your web.php routes file, and move it to your api.php routes file. After that, you can prepend the URL with the api prefix. All that said, I see below you have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `web.php` was not working at all because of caching issues. Running:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

made it work again and showed every problem, which could not be detected before clearing the cache.